Why would Send rearrange string?
My code:
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0+ 
TextToSend := FileRead("textToSend.txt")
lines := StrSplit(TextToSend, "\n")

:*:st::{
    Loop    
        {
        SetKeyDelay 10000
        Send(lines[A_Index])
        Send, {Enter}
        Sleep 10000
    }
}

It used to work fine, but now the lines are rearranged. Say one line is:
abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz

Then it is sent as:
abcdhijkmnopqrstuvwxyzefg

Why is it the case?

The content of textToSend.txt: Pastebin (password: 8mzx6ujPdS).
The first 5 output lines:
52m NGUYỄN THỊ TRANG 73 | PL 17/4/2024 | 8 A 4 Đông Nhì, Lái Thiêu, Thuận An, Bình Dương | 203 | 8 A 4 Đông Nhì, Lái Thiêu, Thuận An, Bình Dương | 7.281.533đ | Na Khu Chế Xuất Linh Trung 2, Bình Chiểu, Thủ Đức, Hồ Chí Minh | 0824831562
ChochNGUYNTHT, Công ty Tài chính Ngân hàng Việt Nam Thịnh Vượng SMBC FC liên lạc để nhắc nhở về khoản vay có số hợp đồng là 20220717-2950586 của chị đến hạn cần thanh toán. Chị có thể thanh toán qua các điểm thu hộ toàn quốc như bưu điện, Thế Giới Di Động, Điện Máy Xanh, app Momo, v.v. Chị thanh toán 3.000.000đ trước 15:00 ngày 14/11/2024. Sau thời gian trên, nếu chị chưa thanh toán, sẽ có nhân viên tiếp tục liên lạc gửi thư báo từ công ty về địa chỉ của chị. Vui lòng thanh toán đúng hạn để tránh phát sinh những hệ lụy ảnh hưởng mà chị đã cam kết trong điều khoản hợp đồng.GRAN
20mBITHỊ NHỎ 76 | CRC 1/6/2023 | Bình Nhâm Tỉnh Bình Dương Tỉnh Bình Dương, ??, ??, Bình Dương | 390 | Bình Nhâm Tỉnh Bình Dương Tỉnh Bình Dương, ??, ??, Bình Dương | ∅ | Bình Nhâm, ??, ??, ?? | 0812622775
Chochị BÙI THỊ NHỎ, Công ty Tài chính Ngân hàng Việt Nam Thịnh Vượng SMBC FC liên lạc để nhắc nhở về khoản vay có số hợp đồng là 1500040018188853 của chị đến hạn cần thanh toán. Chị có thể thanh toán qua các điểm thu hộ toàn quốc như bưu điện, Thế Giới Di Động, Điện Máy Xanh, app Momo, v.v. Chị thanh toán 3.000.000đ trước 15:00 ngày 14/11/2024. Sau thời gian trên, nếu chị chưa thanh toán, sẽ có nhân viên tiếp tục liên lạc gửi thư báo từ công ty về địa chỉ của chị. Vui lòng thanh toán đúng hạn để tránh phát sinh những hệ lụy ảnh hưởng mà chị đã cam kết trong điều khoản hợp đồng.
32mVTH HƯƠNG 84 | CRC 1/10/2024 | ∅, Bình Hòa, Thuận An, Bình Dương | 180 | ∅, Bình Hòa, Thuận An, Bình Dương | 1.276.713đ | Số 96 B Phố, Định Công, Hoàng Mai, Hà Nội | 0329906019Ị

Documentation: Send - Syntax & Usage | AutoHotkey v2

You should utilize the clipboard and paste large amounts of text. If pasting is not possible, you should use SendInput.

Try to place Sleep at the beginning of the loop, not at the end. 3 seconds are enough for me:
:*:st::{
  Loop    
      {
      Sleep 3000
      Send(lines[A_Index] "{Enter}")
  }
}


Two things I noticed that aren't in line with AHK v2 syntax:
StrSplit(TextToSend, "\n") - The line break in AHK should be specified as "`n" and not "\n".
Send, {Enter} - Send in AHK v2 should be encapsulated with " or '.
I tested it here with the code below, adjusting the syntax, and for me, it's sending in the correct order.
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0+ 
TextToSend := FileRead("textToSend.txt")
lines := StrSplit(TextToSend, "`n")

:*:st::{
    Loop lines.Length ; Prevents an error when attempting to execute a loop in an invalid range
        {
        SetKeyDelay 10000
        Send( lines[A_Index] '{Enter}')
        Sleep 10000
    }

}

